# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{2n\choose k}\frac{1}{4^{n}}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}{2n\choose k}\frac{1}{4^{n}}$ is?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{2n\choose k}\frac{1}{4^{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{2n}$

using $(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2!}....$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}=1+\frac{2n}{4^n}+\frac{2n(2n-1)}{4^{2n}2!}....$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}=\frac{2n}{4^n}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}=\frac{2}{4^n\ln4}$

all terms vanish we are left with $1$ only.

Am I correct that limit is $1$?

Comment: This makes no sense without specifying the summation index and limits.

Comment: The limit is $1$, but your reasoning isn't correct. Just because the terms in an infinite sum go to zero does not mean their sum does.

Comment: @MartinR edited

Comment: You should start the summation with $k=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find the limit of $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n} \binom {2n} {k} \frac  1{4^{k}}$ then you can write the sum  as $(1+\frac 1 {4})^{2n}=(\frac 5  4 )^{2n}$ and the limit is $\infty$

However, if you want to find the limit of $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n} \binom {2n} {k} \frac  1{4^{n}}$ then the answer is obviously $1$ since the value is $1$ for every $n$.

Comment: @Crostul how limit is $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Daman I have edited my answer.

Comment: What if there was \frac{1}{4^{n}}. Actually, this came in the exam yester and I am not sure what it was exactly.

Comment: @Daman I have answered that also. You get $(1+1)^{2n}/4^{n}$ which is just $1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Sir there were two answers saying it was $\frac{1}{2} $ what is wrong I am confused.

Comment: The other two answers are taking the sum  from $k=0$ to $k=n$ But you have clearly typed the sum  from $k=0$ to $2n$ So my answer is the correct one.  @Daman

Comment: How did you obtain the exponent $n$ in $\frac1{4^n}$ while summing $\binom{2n}k\frac1{4^k}$?

Comment: @user Thanks. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Sir i checked sum goes go n not 2n could u please tell me the answer now? I will update my question.

Comment: Changing  the question 4 days after it has been answered and approved is not proper. Please keep  the sum up to $2n$ and ask a  separate question. @Daman

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused

Answer (score 4):

For the first sum we have
$$\begin {align}
S_n&=\frac1{4^n}\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n}k\\
&=\frac1{4^n}\times\frac12\left[{2^{2n}+\binom{2n}n}-2\right]\\
&=\frac12\left[1+\binom{2n}n\frac1{4^n}-\frac2{4^n}\right],
\end {align}$$
which implies:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\frac12.
$$
Similarly the second sum is 1.

The proofs of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}n\frac1{4^n}=0\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{4^n}=0 $$
are left as exercises.

Comment: Th summation is up to $2n$, not $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Originally it was $\sum_{k=0}^n$

Comment: @Crostul Yes Sorry for that I have edited it

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Originally the summation was up to $n$. The answer is now corrected (and is much simpler).

Comment: @user It was upto $n$ I checked what is the answer now sir?

Comment: @Daman I rolled back to my initial answer.

Comment: @Daman Does the sum start with $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Please update your answer accordingly sorry for inconvenience caused

Comment: @user I gave an exam. I am not sure what was the question. Thats why it caused that much problem. Ignore it please.

Comment: @Daman The limits are $\frac12$ and $1$ for the first and the second  sums, respectively (for both start values of $k$).